# Why is perf not working for precise events in my Intel Skylake Server?

Tags: server, intel, performancecounter, perf

I wanted to measure the percentage of remote and local memory accesses in my workloads. I am facing some issues, as I feel I am not getting correct numbers for the events mem_load_l3_miss_retired.remote_dram and mem_load_l3_miss_retired.local_dram on my Skylake Server. 
So I wanted to make use of Precise events. But to my surprise, I am getting the event as not supported in the machine. Although the Manual mentions the counter as a PEBS counter.

My output is as follows:

```
perf stat -e mem_load_l3_miss_retired.remote_dram:p sleep 2

Performance counter stats for 'sleep 2':

   <not supported>      mem_load_l3_miss_retired.remote_dram:p
```

Please help me in getting to the solution.

Comment: Do events in general work, like `instructions`, if you run `perf stat /bin/ls`?  If you're in a VM without PMU pass-through, you won't be able to use HW events.

Comment: Yes normally all counters are working. 
mem_load_l3_miss_retired.remote_dram:u, mem_load_l3_miss_retired.remote_dram:k and even mem_load_l3_miss_retired.remote_dram works. 
It is just that it is not working when I wanted to use the Precise mode. 

Note: I am not on a VM. I am on the server itself and also have sudo privilages.

Comment: @PeterCordes Actually without using the PEBS counter, I am doubting the counts given to me by mem_load_l3_miss_retired.remote_dram and mem_load_l3_miss_retired.local_dram on certain circumstances. So I wanted to checkiout the Precise mode readings.

Comment: Presumably that event doesn't support PEBS.  Not all do.  Keep in mind that Precise just refers to which instruction the sample is attributed to (matters for `perf record`), as well as PEBS reducing interrupt overhead by having a buffer for sampled.  Non-PEBS mode should still accurately report the total for `perf stat`.  (But check the published errata for your CPU; there are some involving perf events that can lead to bogus counts for some events.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot obtain `Precise` event numbers with `perf stat`.

`perf stat` runs in non-sampling mode, wherein `perf` maintains a running count of all occurrences of events. It does not make sense to record `Precise events` in counting mode. `Precise events`, as Peter mentioned, helps you to correctly narrow down the instruction (actually +1 instruction, from the instruction that triggers the PEBS assist), which the record in the sample is attributed to.

Also, the PEBS interrupt-handler is known to cause conflicts with the counter overflow NMI that runs when `perf stat` is run. For more understanding, you should look at [this](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/1482931866-6018-3-git-send-email-jolsa@kernel.org/) discussion.

For the above reasons, recording `precise` events has been disabled in non-sampling mode, as can be seen [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.14/source/arch/x86/events/core.c#L508).

```
/* There's no sense in having PEBS for non sampling events: */
    if (!is_sampling_event(event))
            return -EINVAL;
```

You should use `perf record` to record `precise` events, since it seems that event `mem_load_l3_miss_retired.remote_dram` has support for PEBS [already](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.14/source/tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/x86/skylakex/cache.json#L630).

```
perf record -e mem_load_l3_miss_retired.remote_dram:p sleep 2
```